# im trying to save cookies so that next time i log in i wont have to sign in again but its just giving me an error

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, pickle, whatsapp

```
import pickle
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver
import options
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

the error that i am getting is: NameError: name 'Options' is not defined
am i doing soomething tottaly wrong. im trying to save the cookies so that next time i can login in to my whatsapp without having to manualy do the qr code

Comment: Try: `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

Comment: its still not working. are you able to give me the full code that works

Comment: No, I won't be able to give you "_the full code that works_" because that's not how things work here. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `import pickle
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
`